# Get input data from list of elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get a list of sizes available from a certain shoe from nike.

All sizes are listed in a `<li>`, including abled and disabled sizes.
When I call on console `document.getElementsByClassName('tamanho__item_pdp js-tamanho__item_pdp')` it returns a HTMLCollection with all the abled sizes and their inside code.

Each size returns this `<input type="radio" class="tamanho__item_pdp js-tamanho__item_pdp" data-tamanho="36" data-codigoproduto="194495234016" name="tamanho__id" id="tamanho__id36" value="https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Produto/Daybreak/153-169-211-222753">`.

There is some way that i can get only the `data-tamanho` which is the size number?And if possible a list containing all the avaliable sizes.

If it helps the site link that I am trying the code is :[Nike Daybreak](https://www.nike.com.br/Snkrs/Produto/Daybreak/153-169-211-222737)

Answer (score 1):

Since you get the list of elements, you can parse it an return a new array with only the sizes:

```
let sizes = document.getElementsByClassName('tamanho__item_pdp js-tamanho__item_pdp');
```

To get the size values, just parse the `sizes` array:

```
let values = Array.from(sizes).map((input) => input.getAttribute('data-tamanho'));
// ["36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Both [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) create a new array. Isn't `map` enough?

Comment: Hi @Pynchia. No, `map` on it own is not enough in this context. `sizes`, as @Camlost pointed out, is an `HTMLCollection`. It doesn't have the `map` method.

Comment: I see, thank you. I am new to Js and coming from Python I must say things look quite odd sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `.dataset` on each element to get `data-` attributes:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('tamanho__item_pdp js-tamanho__item_pdp')[0].dataset.tamanho
```

You can loop over each result and access the `.dataset.tamanho` property to get each of the sizes